# how to convert WebElement to string in selenium using java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

I am not able to convert webelement to string values.

```
 List<WebElement> a=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]"));
```

i want convert above `List<WebElement>` to `String`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It does not make sense to convert object to a string. What you probably want is to  access some of the attributes of the object which are strings, like text and/or value.

Comment: Actually i want to getText from webelement and write that text into excel. That's why want to convert webelement into string so that i will able to write into excel.

Comment: Exactly. So you **DON'T** want to convert element to string but elem.getText() of it.

Comment: Yeah. But how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
List<WebElement> links =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]"));

String []linkText =new String[links.size()];
int i=0;

//Storing List elements text into String array
for(WebElement a: links)
{
   linkText[i]=a.getText();
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you can do it using java 8 features:

```
By byXpath = By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]");
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(byXpath);

List<String> texts = links.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will iterate through each WebElement, call getText, and collect all the returned values into a brand new list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @FindBys({
        @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class=\"error-text text--center margin--bottom_10\"]")
})
private List<WebElement> errorTexts;

  private List<String> getAllErrorsText() {
    return errorTexts.stream()
            .map(WebElement::getText)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```